# Prove that closure of A = intersection of A + U for all open neighbourhoods of 0 U

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

The definition I am using (in a topological vector space) is that cl(A) is defined to be the intersection of all closed sets containing A. I am being asked to show that:

cl(A) = $\cap (A+U)$, where U spans over all open sets containing 0.

Comment: What's "+"?  Do you mean all open sets containing $A$?

Comment: It's a topological vector space, so there is a + defined. It's just the set of all a + u, a in A, u in U.

Comment: I suggest describing what you've tried so far, or giving some more context, to avoid more downvotes (the one you got is not from me).

Answer (score 7):

Let $x\in cl(A)$ and $U$ be a open set containing $0$. Then $x-U$ is an open set containing $x$. Since $x \in cl(A)$, $(x-U) \cap A \neq \emptyset$. This means $\exists u\in U, a\in A$ such that $x-u=a \Rightarrow x=a+u \Rightarrow x\in A+U$. But since U was arbitrary, $x\in \cap (A+U)$ where U spans over all open sets containing $0$.

Conversely, let $x\in \cap (A+U)$ where U spans over all open sets containing $0$. Let $V$ be any open set containing $x$. Then $U=-x+V$ is a neighbourhood of $0$. $-U$ is also a neighbourhood of $0$.
$\Rightarrow x\in A-U$. So $\exists a \in A, u\in U$ such that $x=a-u$.
$\Rightarrow a=x+u$.

Now, $u\in U=-x+V \Rightarrow u=-x+v$, for some $v \in V$. 
So $a=x+u=x-x+v=v$. That is, $a \in V$. So $a\in A \cap V \Rightarrow A \cap V \neq \emptyset$ for any neighbourhood of $V$ of $X$. Thus $x\in cl(A)$.